# Need to exclude first post from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to exclude first post from wordpress loop on archive.php page. The loop code is this.

```
<div class="article-container">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'archive' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways. You can use a counter or boolean variable. This example uses the latter (I don't know what you are using 'global $post_i; $post_i = 1;' for but you could use $post_i as a counter, increment it in the while loop and use a condition, if that was your intention):

```
<div class="article-container">
    <?php global $post_i; $post_i = 1; ?>
    <?php $show_post = false; ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($show_post === false): ?>
    <?php $show_post = true; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'archive' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Tokant, This golobal variable comes default with wordpress theme. Please have a look at this github page [link](https://github.com/themegrill/colormag/blob/master/archive.php)

Comment: I have 8 post on each page, now its showing only 7 post on each page. So I think this code delete first post from each page instead of only latest (first) post.

Comment: Hi! My conditional works despite the $post_i variable being used in your template part. You didn't mention that your archive post is shown by date in ascending order (from old to new). In that case you need to use the found_posts in your query and do a conditional based on that total number.

Comment: Is it possible to remove first post only on the first page ?

Comment: My code already removes the first post in the while loop. What you mean is 'how to remove the latest post?' (which can be the first or last depending on your archived posts order; in your specific case it is the last post in the while loop).

Comment: Your code removes first post from every pagination page. I have 8 post on a page (it works for that page). When I go to previous page with pagination, then it again removes the first post on that page. So basically it removes 1st, 8th, 16th and so on post and it continues removing on every pagination page. Hope you are getting my point. I need only first post to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Then hook into the 'pre_get_posts' and offset the query by 1. Add this to your functions file:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'offset_posts_wordpress_archive', 50);
function offset_posts_wordpress_archive($query){

    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_archive()){
        $query->set('offset', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now its showing same 8 post on every pagination page